# How to save image file to string in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image

I want to read Image file(png, jpg, etc).
and save xml file, load image from xml.

but first. Deserialize throw System.InvalidOperationException.
second. I don't know below method is correct.



**Scenario.**
1. Open Image file from hdd.
2. Save document(text with image like 'SomeClass' in below source) in my application.
3. When save document, application will serialize SomeClass with image.
4. Rerun application, and load xml file.
5. then, show image in my application.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\z.jpg")))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    someClass.ImageData = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Xml.Serialize<SomeClass>(someClass, @"C:\z.xml");
}

 SomeClass someClass = Xml.Deserialize<SomeClass>(@"C:\z.xml");

 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
 image.BegineInit();
 image.Source = ??
 image.EndInit();

 System.Windows.Controls.Image imageControl = new Image();
 imageControl.Source = image;

 this.Content = imageControl;
```

this is Serialize, Deserialize static method.

```
public static class Xml
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(T data, string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            s.Serialize(fs, data);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.Position = 0;
            return (T)s.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

This is SomeClass

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public string ImageData { get; set; }
    public string TextData { get; set; }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: See the section **Debugging Serialization Code** in the MSDN documentation [*Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the binary image data to a string.  You can use the Convert methods to handle that.

**Edit note** - Noticed you were reading all bytes into a memory stream and then reading them again from a stream reader.  It would simplify the code to just read it directly and convert those bytes to Base64.

Example below.

```
someClass.ImageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\z.jpg"));
Xml.Serialize<SomeClass>(someClass, @"C:\z.xml");

------------------

SomeClass someClass = Xml.Deserialize<SomeClass>(@"C:\z.xml");

BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BegineInit();
image.Source = Convert.FromBase64String(someClass.ImageData);
image.EndInit();
```

Comment: Because I do not know speak English, it is difficult to understand.
Can you explain in an easy vocabulary?

Comment: @user3214694 - You cannot store binary data in XML. It has to be converted to a string. You can use Base64 encoding to store it. That is what my example shows you how to do.

Comment: @pstrjds Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: @pstrjds wow. amazing. this way is correct. it works good. Thanks you.

Comment: @user3214694 - Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved the problem.